# JSF download and forward to a result page

Tags: java, jsf, download

I am using  JSF 2.1 and Primefaces. When a user submits a form my program fills a PDF document and download that to users computer, then I need to show a new page with a status message.My code downloads the filled form but not redirects to a result page.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("C:/Backup/test.pdf");
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
....
```

fills the fileds here..

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\""); 
response.setHeader("Refresh", "1; URL=result.xhtml");

BufferedOutputStream output = null;
output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
document.save(output);
output.close();
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Comment: You might be calling `responseComplete()` a little too late in the lifecycle. Move it to just after retrieving the `HttpServletResponse`. Also make sure the control that triggers the download is not ajax-enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow one of these:

1. **Option 1**

   i.  Redirect the user to the Result page

   ii. Show user a **Download Button**, when this button is clicked, open a new window where PDF will be shown/downloaded.
2. **Opntion 2**

   i. Redirect the user to the Result page

   ii. When the result page loads, using javascript/jQuery send a request to open a new window where PDF will be shown/downloaded.